# Does appending a list slice back to the original list just copy the addresses?

Tags: python, list, copy

If I have a list of objects as such in Python:

```
li = [obj1, obj2, obj3, ob4, obj5]
```

And I append the last two objects to the end of the list again:

```
li.extend(li[-2:])
```

Do duplicates in `li` now have the same or different addresses? If I make changes to one of the elements of the array that has been appended to the end of the list `li`, will the duplicate at the end also change? Is there a better way to preform this copy if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same addresses - you can check this with [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). If the elements of the list are mutable, then modifying one will modify the other. If the elements of the list are immutable, then you cannot modify them.

```
li = [1, 1.0, None, ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd')]

li.extend(li[-2:])
print(li)
# outputs [1, 1.0, None, ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd'), ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd')]

li[-2].pop()
print(li)
# outputs [1, 1.0, None, ['a'], ('c', 'd'), ['a'], ('c', 'd')]
# Note that elemnts at indices -2 and -4 have changed since id(li[-2]) == id(li[-4])

print(id(li[-1]) == id(li[-3]))
# True
```

To add deep copies, you can use the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

```
li = [1, 1.0, None, ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd')]

li.extend(list(map(copy.deepcopy, li[-2:])))
print(li)
# outputs [1, 1.0, None, ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd'), ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd')]

li[-2].pop()
print(li)
# outputs [1, 1.0, None, ['a', 'b'], ('c', 'd'), ['a'], ('c', 'd')]
# Note that only the list at index -2 has changed since id(li[-2]) != id(li[-4])
```

Note that for immutable objects, `copy.deepcopy` does not make a copy of the object unless that object has references to other mutable objects. So in the last list `id(li[-1]) == id(li[-3])`.

Comment: Another part of my question is: 'Is there a way to do this such that a real copy is made?'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, python will *reference* the same object in memory if you use the `extend()` method in this way, if this is your desired outcome, then simply execute:

```
li.extend(li[-2:])
```

Example:

```
a = object()
b = object()
c = object()
d = object()
# Alternatively a, b, c, d = object(), object(), object(), object()
li = [a, b, c, d]
```

Now we check out our list `li`:

```
[<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0b0>, 
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0c0>, 
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0d0>,  # c
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0e0>]  # d
```

Running your operation on `li`, *notice* the memory address':

```
[<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0b0>, 
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0c0>, 
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0d0>,
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0e0>, 
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0d0>,  # <- Same object as c
<object object at 0x7fb84a31e0e0>]  # <- Same object as d
```

You'll notice that the last two elements that were appended are indeed the **same** objects in memory as what the variables `c` and `d` are assigned to. This means that making changes to the last two objects in the list will also change the objects at index 2 *and* 3.

Now if you wanted to add copy's of the last two elements, you could do the following:

```
extend_elements = [copy.deepcopy(i) for i in li[-2:]]
li.extend(extend_elements)
```

Please refer to [Python's copy module doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for copy operations.